# How can I make ipython display deprecation warnings for python 3 porting issues?

Tags: python-2.7, ipython

The python 2.7.x interpreter has an option to turn on deprecation warnings

```
-3     : warn about Python 3.x incompatibilities that 2to3 cannot trivially fix
```

How do I tell ipython to turn on this warning ?